# qtmqtt can not connect to server

Tags: c++, qt, mqtt

QtMqtt cannot connect to the server, but I can connect normally using other test software.The server is mosquitto on Ubuntu.

```
 m_client= new QMqttClient(this);
 m_client->setProtocolVersion(QMqttClient::MQTT_3_1_1);
 m_client->setPort(1883);
 m_client->setHostname("127.0.0.1");
 m_client->setClientId("qt");
 m_client->connectToHost();

connect(m_client,SIGNAL(stateChanged(ClientState)),this,SLOT(slot_stateChanged()),Qt::UniqueConnection);

void slot_stateChanged()
{
    qDebug() << "mqtt stsate" << _client->state();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using a broker at localhost, maybe you should connect the signal slot before calling the `connectToHost()`

try with

```
m_client= new QMqttClient(this);
//connect signal slot


connect(m_client,SIGNAL(stateChanged(ClientState)),this,SLOT(slot_stateChanged()),Qt::UniqueConnection);

//connect to borker
 m_client->setProtocolVersion(QMqttClient::MQTT_3_1_1);
 m_client->setPort(1883);
 m_client->setHostname("127.0.0.1");
 m_client->setClientId("qt");
 m_client->connectToHost();


void slot_stateChanged()
{
    qDebug() << "mqtt stsate" << _client->state();
}
```